# How can I add a tween in PhaserJS to keep moving the object further from where it stopped?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, phaser-framework, tween

The need is to run the object and stop, now run further and stop and so on, according to the number parameter of the function.
If I add `repeat` in the tween, it starts from the original starting point on repeat.

I tried to add iterators with the tweens with for loop also. But they don't give pauses on the stops. I added `delay` and `completeDelay` to get the pause but to no use. It just runs straight to the final destination. I even tried setTimeout but no help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for some time I used tween timeline in the Phaser liabrary. It worked perfectly with a for loop also. 
@Adam Nijjar's solution is also working :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a method i use to accomplish this and it doesn't involve the need of the "repeat" parameter.
you can add your tween in a function and add onComplete that calls this tween's function.
For example: (tween that makes object go up)

```
function goAbove(yourTarget){
 this.tweens.add({
    targets: yourTarget,
    y: youTarget.y + newY,
    ease: "Linear",
    duration: duration,
    yoyo: false,
    onComplete: goAbove.bind(this, yourTarget),
  });
}
```

yourTarget will keep going up endlessly unless you add an if condition inside the tween's function which makes it stop when a specific value is reached, for example:

```
if ( yourTarget.y < 300 ){
  this.tweens.add({
    targets: yourTarget,
    y: youTarget.y + newY,
    ease: "Linear",
    duration: duration,
    yoyo: false,
    onComplete: goAbove.bind(this, yourTarget),
  });
}
```

This above will stop the tween from repeating when yourTarget.y becomes greater then 300.
Hope this helps!

Comment: This looks useful. But after searching for some time I used tween timeline in the Phaser liabrary. It worked perfectly with a for loop also.
Thanks... your solution is also working :)